# "Blog pages show at most" in The Loop

Tags: loop

I remember in another theme I did, that the The Loop automatically looped for the number that was set in "Blog pages show at most" (Settings->Reading). The theme I am working on right now does not see to consider this number and loops for an infinite amount of time (and crashes of course). How do I make it to consider "Blog pages show at most" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable guesses that come to my mind are that the theme (or a plugin):

1. Modifies the main Query with a filter on `pre_get_posts`, so look
   for that filter.
2. Just creates a new Loop with `new WP_Query($args)`. You will have to dig through the template file to find out.
3. Interrupts the `post_per_page` save process or alter the
   `posts_per_page` option in the database, so check the `*_options`
   table for the `posts_per_page` key (option_name) to rule that out.
4. The Loop is not calling `the_post`. Without that, the Loop will
   never increment to the next post and the loop will run until the
   browser gives up.

I'd bet on #1, then #2, with #3 being a distant third. Without more information I can't give a solid answer.

Item #4 is a very viable option but the problem is not the query itself but the Loop.

Comment: Ok, so the main query of the home page never sets the post_per_page to the "Blog pages show at most" value by default? What is the default value to posts_per_page?

Comment: `get_option('posts_per_page')` will get you the value saved in the database.

Comment: But was is the default value of posts_per_page in the main query?

Comment: That is the default in the main query, and I believe should be the default in any query unless specifically instructed otherwise.

Comment: If it is the default in the main query, why does it loop an infinite amount of times? Isn't it suppose to loop for the number of times that was set in Settings->Reading?

Comment: I told you the possibilities I can think of. Without analyzing the theme code I can't answer you with much detail.

Comment: It's still a blank theme. I have only an index.php and i'm just trying to show the 10 last posts (10 is the value that I set in Settings->Reading). The Loop will loop for too long (and crash, I have to many post to show in one query), instead of only showing the 10 last posts. I guess the default value to posts_per_page is not the value that was set in Settings -> Reading?

Comment: Just thought of option #4.

Comment: Ahhh no, the loop is calling the_post();
This is not the problem :/.
Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Ok so you were right, posts_per_page get it's default value in Settings->Reading and is always in the main query. I forgot to put parentheses after have_posts... Stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem using pagination (not infinite loop).  It seems that the "Blog pages show at most" controls how many total pages are available and does not realize how many posts are actually being shown....

For instance, if my category has 113 posts, and I show 10 results per page (using $args(posts-per-page = 10)) I should expect to have 11 pages... but since my "Blog pages show at most" is set to 20, I only have 6 pages available. This is what I figured out:

```
PAGE               RESULTS EXPECTED         RESULTS GIVEN
1                  POSTS #1-10              POSTS #1-10
2                  POSTS #11-20             POSTS #21-30
3                  POSTS #21-30             POSTS #61-70
4                  POSTS #31-40             POSTS #81-90
5                  POSTS #41-50             POSTS #101-113
6                  POSTS #51-60             404 Error
7                  POSTS #61-70             404 Error
8                  POSTS #71-80             404 Error
9                  POSTS #81-90             404 Error
10                 POSTS #91-100            404 Error
11                 POSTS #101-113           404 Error
```

As you can realize, I had a lot of posts missing from my list, and since my posts aren't numbered, it was difficult to figure out.

**How to fix:** 
Set your "Blog pages show at most" to a number LOWER than your lowest post-per-page.  That way, Wordpress will allot enough pages for your query to complete... otherwise, you will get an error because the total pages expected by the plugin or your own code will exceed what Wordpress believes you should have.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore the global setting for one custom query but leave it intact for others, you can just save the value of the option to a temp variable, update_option('posts_per_page', '') to your custom posts_per_page, and then at the end of your work reassign the original global value back to the option like so:

```php
      $posts_per_page = 3;      
      $global_posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
      update_option('posts_per_page', strval($posts_per_page));

      // WP custom loop and work here

      update_option('posts_per_page', $global_posts_per_page);
```

It adds a couple extra writes to the database but I think you'll live.