# How to find out what "Blog pages show at most" is set to

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, get-posts

Under **Settings** > **Reading**, there is a field called **Blog pages show at most __  posts**. Since all of my queries are based off of the main query, I need to find out what's stored in that field. How would I do that, especially outside of the loop?

Comment: Or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105645/blog-pages-show-at-most-in-the-loop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get that value with

```
get_option('posts_per_page');
```